# Create reports in Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I want to create a report in Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008 but I don't know how can I do that. I create a report in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio but I don't know the relation between this report and Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008.

How can I use Reporting Services and create a report in it?

Answer (score 2):

The report server is where you store your reports so that people can run them centrally. You can deploy your report from BIDS to the report server.

You can also log in to the report server and run a tool called report builder to create and deploy reports without having to use BIDS.

Have a look at the following link for how to get started with reporting services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522672(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: these web pages can't help me . I don't understand what must I do . can you help me more?

Comment: Ok then, here is a link to a tutorial you can follow on creating a report: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b539b4b-26f2-4c0b-b506-80f175679a46

Comment: I create report and deploy it and it's ok , but is Reporting Services in SQL Server is it?

Comment: It's a component of SQL server, yes. It's a separate component to the database engine. Usually you access it via a web browser at http://server/Reports

Answer (score 0):

Since you already create report, you can directly upload your .rdl file directly to reporting service. If you don't know how to configure your reporting service, please refer to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159868%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) . You can also use reporting service manage URL to see your uploaded report, and you can also open from there to use report builder to directly edit your report.

Comment: I create report and deploy it and it's ok , but is Reporting Services in SQL Server is it?